# execute a code only when a particular method completes an API request in angular 4

Tags: angular, api, angular-material, observable

Suppose I have two methods: Method One and Method Two. Method One has a call inside Method Two as below:

```
variable;

methodOne(){
    this.variable;
    // A API call which sets the value of "variable"
};

methodTwo(){
    this.methodOne();

    if(this.variable!= null){
        // using data in variable for other operations
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when `methodTwo` is called it internally calls `methodOne`, which sets value of "variable" by the data returned by the API. But the code after the `methodOne` call in `methodTwo` gets executed before the "variable" data is set and the value of variable is always null.

Answer (score 0):

```
methodOne(){
      
   // return this.http.get('whatever');

};

methodTwo(){

      this.methodOne().subscribe((whateverResponse)=>{

          // set this.variable here with whateverResponse

          if(this.variable !=null){
             // do whatever here.
          }

      });
}
```